# Sentences that end in "by"

Tags: meaning

Sentences that "Talent goes by", "... passing us by".

What is the *"function"* of "by" in sentence?

Why to use "by"?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case the word 'by' is part of the verb 'to pass by'. The example of 'Talent goes by' is not as clear to me so I can't comment on it. It might or might not be the same type of situation, depending on its context.

The verb 'to pass by' has a different meaning from the verb 'to pass'. To pass something has a concrete meaning. It's a physical action.

> Can you pass me that pencil?
>
> I'm going to pass that car if it doesn't speed up.
>
> A whole generation will pass into adulthood.

The verb 'to pass by' has a more abstract meaning. It means to overlook or ignore.

> He was sad because life had passed him by.

You can recognize this type of verb because the object of the verb is placed before the word 'by'. Don't confuse this with using the preposition 'by' with the verb 'to pass'. In this case the word 'by' comes before the object of the verb.

> On my way to work I usually pass by the grocery store.